# Meteor /w Angular 2.0 db doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, meteor

Today I came across server-client framework Meteor.js, I started with their beginners tutorial togather with Angular 2.0, I am currently stuck already at third step ["Meteor tutorial"](http://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/angular2/3-way-data-binding)

So basiclly I just have to connect their to database and test Meteor's power, the problem is that even that I was able to connect to the Meteor's database through command line, insert an object there, the data can't be fetched in the app itself. 
I was following the tutorial,

so that's my **app.ts** file:

```
    /// <reference path="../typings/angular2-meteor.d.ts" />

    import {Component, View, NgFor} from 'angular2/angular2';

    import {Parties} from 'collections/parties';

    import {bootstrap} from 'angular2-meteor';

    @Component({
    selector: 'app'
    })

    @View({
    templateUrl: 'client/app.html',
    directives: [NgFor]
    })

  class Socially {
    parties: Array<Object>;

    constructor () {
      Tracker.autorun(zone.bind(() => {

        this.parties = Parties.find().fetch();
      }));

    }
  }

  bootstrap(Socially);
```

**parties.ts**

```
     /// <reference path="../typings/angular2-meteor.d.ts" />
     export var Parties = new Mongo.Collection('parties');
```

and **app.html**

```
Do you even work ;c
<ul>

    <li *ng-for="#party of parties">
        {{party.name}}
        <p>{{party.description}}</p>

    </li>
</ul>
```

I've also read a bit about Meteor's kind of a local database and if I try to add an object to the local store like that

```
   Parties._collection.insert({name:"test", description: "test desc"});
```

The data is displayed properly, but even though I have data in the server database (added through command line) it doesn't get displayed...

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the server files (server/main.ts and server/load_parties.ts) if you haven't. This solved the problem for me.